# Having issues loading django admin static files

Tags: python, django, web, django-admin

Im having issues loading the static files for django admin using the latest django. Now i have tried multiple methods and really would appreciate help. For info im using pythonanywhere for deployment.

```
This is the settings.py file 


 """
Django settings for MyDjangoApp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.15.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import server_keys as sk

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = sk.django_key

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.22','localhost','username.pythonanywhere.com ','username.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'regs',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MyDjangoApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['regs/templates/regs'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MyDjangoApp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kuwait'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/username/main/static"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
    ]
```

Based off of most tutorial and guides you would just set the path and run py manage.py collectstatic
and then it would work, but wasn't the case for me. I also got the normal static files to load but not the django admin.

My directory looks something like this: /home/username/main/Projectroot
and in the python anywhere i put the url as "static" and root as /home/username/main/static.

If im missing anymore info please let me know, i would love to deploy my project and get over this simple but annoying part, thank you!

Comment: did you try STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ? and run collectstatic again ?

Comment: Yes i have tried this method and still won't load the admin files.

Comment: There is a help page on PythonAnywhere to help you debug static files mappings: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles/

Comment: i dont have issues finding my static files that are made by me. I have issues loading the admin page's static files.

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I am no pro

Since you are using a virtual env, the admin files are located where you installed django, you can confirm it by running `python manage.py findstatic admin/js/core.js`.

check out [django static files doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) to see more.

A hack I used(dev server) was to copy this files into my base `/static/admin` folder.